# Wireless adapter speed changes

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, xubuntu, adapter

I have an Xubuntu desktop in another part of house from router. I use a USB wireless adapter to connect. At first it works with a speed of 72 Mb/s. Then intermittently it will drop to 7 Mb/s for various numbers of seconds then back to 72 Mb/s. This keeps happening with the computer idle, no browser running. There does not seem to be any pattern to the times. I can restore to 72 by disconnecting and reconnecting the network, but it only lasts a little while.

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0d8c:0201 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM6501
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Start by posting the output of `lsusb`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a driver problem, however, it could simply be interference in your home (another wireless signal etc).

There are a few best practises for placing your router in your home; see if any of these may apply:

- Place router in a central location (centre of your home)
- Avoid metal objects near your router (microwaves etc)
- Avoid placing near walls
- Try mounting it up high for further reach
- Find the antenna's optimal position (if your router's antenna is external)
- Avoid rooms where a lot of people will be (human's water mass can interfere with wifi signal too)
- Try changing the channel your wifi uses (on your router conf page)

Source: [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/27/wifi-router-placement-tips_n_6943024.html)

Answer (score 0):

If this was interference or weak signal then I would think it would stay at the low speed. It may just be a power saving mode.

Try:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 get power_save
```

If it's on, then run

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

See if that helps. Replace wlan0 with your WiFi adapters name.